# is a test for (b === null) the same as a just (b)?

Tags: javascript

If I have code that looks like this with a test for `===`

```
var a = (b === null) ? "" : 888;
```

then is this the same as just placing the variable name inside () ?

```
var a = (b) ? "" : 888;
```

Comment: No. In fact it is close to the opposite. `(b)` will be `false` if `b` is `null` (or anything not truthy). But `(b === null)` will be `true` if `b` is `null`. :-)

Comment: If a null value is tested as a simple single condition it will result as false. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2WXFH/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b === null` will check if `b` have same type, in your case `null`, just checking for `(b)` will check for `undefined`, `Boolean`, `Int`, `null` and `String` values.

Answer (score 1):

in javascript we can easily cast all kinds of values to a boolean just with using them as a boolean, and there are some values which presents the false value like:

```
null
""
undefined
0
false
```

the other point is, `==` compares the values of object and works with `valueOf()` objects,
but `===` compare the object instances.

For example:

```
var MyClass = function(){};
MyClass.prototype.valueOf = function(){return 12;};
var obj = new MyClass();
console.log(obj==12);//result is true
```

BUT

```
console.log(obj===12);//result is false
```

the point is when you compare an object with null like:

```
obj === null
```

it would compare them as 2 different objects, but if you do it like:

```
obj == null; //better way to check the value
```

it would compare the values:

```
var myobj = undefined;
console.log(myobj==null);//result is true
```

But instead of all these lines of codes if you really want a Boolean value you can do it like:

```
obj = !!obj;//this is something like a toBoolean method.
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically == Just compare two variables value, and if requires it will convert datatypes implicitely.

while === will compare two variables value with it's datatype.

Consider this simple example,

```
0==false   // true
0===false  // false, because they are of a different type
1=="1"     // true, auto type coercion
1==="1"    // false, because they are of a different type
```

this is how == and === work.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not the same.

`===` means strict equality, the left hand side and right hand side need to be equal in both type and value.

using the `if (a)` construct, a is checked to be truthy or falsy. Falsy values are for example "" (string), 0 (number), undefined and null.

`if (a)` is almost the same as `if (a !== null && a !== undefined && a !== "" && a !== 0)`